# html layout messed up when i zoom in or out

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where when I zoom in and out the layout of the page gets messed up. I've search for other posts online but not really helped. Maybe it's because of the way I arranged my css. Hopefully someone can explain to me how to fix this problem, thanks. This is how it looks like before and after.

**BEFORE**

[image: Before]

**AFTER**

[image: After]

**HTML**

```
<body>   
<div id="container">
    <div style="position:static">
        <ul class="items">
            <li>ABOUT KDU</li>
            <li style="margin-left:30%;">ADMISSION</li>        
            <img src="kdulogo.png" class="MainImage" 
             style="position:static;"> 
            <li style="margin-left:60%;">CAMPUS LIFE</li>
            <li style="margin-left:75%;">INTERNATIONAL STUDENT</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<div id="blocks">
    <ul id=" Images">
        <li><img src="SCCM.jpg" class="imageSize"></li>
        <li><img src="SCCA.jpg" class="imageSize"></li>
        <li><img src="SOB.jpg" class="imageSize"></li>  
        <li><img src="SHTCA.jpg" class="imageSize" style="margin-
        left:210px;"></li>     
        <li><img src="SOE.jpg" class="imageSize"></li>     
   </ul>         
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: "Futura PT Multilingual W02",Futura,Helvetica,Arial,sans-
    serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
    background: #f5f5f0;  
}


.MainImage{
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    transition: all .6s linear;
}

.items>li{
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.items>li:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: black;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}

#blocks{
    background-color:  #262626;
    width: 100%;
    height: 517;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#blocks >ul>li{
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    border: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}


#Images{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

#Image>li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

.imageSize{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}

.imageSize:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}


#container{ 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Asking for tutorials or other references is not allowed on SO. Also, SO is for asking specific questions about specific problems. Your question is far too broad for this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it's broken the layout like that is because you're using percentages so that means when you're changing the zoom level the widths are being altered to fit the new size of the page which is what is meant to happen.

Changing your CSS to be fixed to a certain degree ***will help remedy this issue but won't fully fix everything because of how it's currently working***. I'd suggest as a good starting point that you change the container `max-width` to something suitable for the design to begin with.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

***However***, you can then use [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change the width of the container depending on the screen size which will respond to the page size appropriately. For example, when the screen size becomes smaller to a tablet or mobile, you could do this (as an example).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    #container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }

}
```

Comment: may i know what do u mean by ur statement "wont fully fix everything because of how it's currently working" is it the method of my implementation of css and html are wrong or something else?

Comment: I meant because you're using percentages so when you zoom in the percentages respond to the screen at it's zoomed in level. So a way around it is to make the container have a maximum width and use media queries so the elements respond to the screen size when zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) for all your web development needs.

The styling of your content is breaking everything.

Fixed a few CSS issues but the way you are implementing it will make it impossible to go down to a responsive level. Also try and keep your HTML and CSS separate (Do not do inline CSS).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div style="position:static">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>ABOUT KDU</li>
        <li>ADMISSION</li>
        <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/cso/images/7/79/Normal_regular_zombie_dummy.png/revision/latest?cb=20120104040300" class="MainImage">
        <li>CAMPUS LIFE</li>
        <li>INTERNATIONAL STUDENT</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="blocks">
    <ul id=" Images">
        <li><img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/cso/images/7/79/Normal_regular_zombie_dummy.png/revision/latest?cb=20120104040300" class="imageSize"></li>
        <li><img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/cso/images/7/79/Normal_regular_zombie_dummy.png/revision/latest?cb=20120104040300" class="imageSize"></li>
        <li><img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/cso/images/7/79/Normal_regular_zombie_dummy.png/revision/latest?cb=20120104040300" class="imageSize"></li>
        <li><img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/cso/images/7/79/Normal_regular_zombie_dummy.png/revision/latest?cb=20120104040300" class="imageSize"></li>
        <li><img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/cso/images/7/79/Normal_regular_zombie_dummy.png/revision/latest?cb=20120104040300" class="imageSize"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: "Futura PT Multilingual W02",Futura,Helvetica,Arial,sans-
    serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
    background: #f5f5f0;
}


.MainImage{
    width: 10%;
    transition: all .6s linear;
    float: left;
}

.items > li{
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    float: left;
    width: 22.5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}


.items>li:hover{
    text-decoration-color: gray;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}

#blocks{
    background-color: #262626;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 717px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#blocks >ul>li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}


#Images{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

#Image>li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

.imageSize{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}

.imageSize:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}


#container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: may i know ur statement "way you are implementing it will make it impossible to go down to a responsive level" does that mean that my css implementations are totally wrong? if there is a problem that im facing is that its very confusing for me to understand how to use the position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

In nested DIVs I had very strange layout distortions in most browsers.
I solved it by adding:

```
    .myDivClass {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        width: (..original with + border-width);
        height: (..original height+ border-height);
    }
```

This sets the border of the Div INSIDE. Dont forget to add the now missing pixels to width and height of the DIV.

Solved the problem, no layout messing up anymore... :)